# How to know defination of a struct in dll?

Tags: c++, dll, name-decoration

I need to use a third party DLL which I don't have header , lib or object file of it just DLL alone, I follow this article "Explicitly Linking to Classes in DLL's" in codeguru and able to user function, c++ class from that DLL but there some function call that need to pass or return a struct like this undecorated function I get from PE Explorer:

```
Undecorated C++ Function:
public: struct SCRIPT_SET_RESULT __thiscall ScriptSet::LoadScriptInPackFile(char const *,int)
```

so how can I know the structure of struct SCRIPT_SET_RESULT ?
or I have to disassemble this dll ?, if so please show me how to do that, I only have a very litle experience with that stuff (only cracked few simple crackme in school). Thanks

Comment: "I need to use a third party DLL which I don't have header , lib or object file of it just DLL alone" > maybe it's about time to obtain it legally?

Comment: It was a dll of an online game, and I intent to write an auto play for it so there no way to "obtain it legally"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to solve your problem. Disassembling can give you examples of how this structure is used but only in the way providing offsets of members which is not very helpful. I think the best is to ask DLL author to send you header, or to google for it...

Comment: Exactly. And even if you could get the definition, the meaning of each member would be unknown.